# selenium python element not interactable error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i made code to register automatically but it's not working
this is my target to click

```
<div id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll" class="CheckBox" tabindex="-1" style="left: 878px; top: 669px; width: 89px; height: 28px;" role="checkbox" aria-label="전체동의 " aria-description="" aria-checked="true" status="focused" userstatus="selected" aria-selected="true"><div id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll:icontext" class="nexacontentsbox" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 87px; height: 26px;"><img class="nexaiconitem" src="./_resource_/_theme_/esky_pc/images/btn_WF_CheS.png"><div class="nexatextitem" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 6px;display:inline-block;">전체동의</div></div></div>
```

i tried this code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll:icontext"]').click()
```

but it keep gives me an error and i also tried this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll:icontext']]").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

and it didn't work either
i tried to do it with script like this

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll:icontext']]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

and it didn't give me an error but it still can't click it
how can i fix this?

```
whole code of my program

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import os

username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
desktop = 'c:\\users\\' + username + '\\desktop\\'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=desktop +"chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.ehaneul.go.kr:5443/esky_p/esky_index.jsp#MENU:M211002000')
sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.btn_M211000000"]').click()
browser = driver
sleep(2)
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

edit
it solved with simple scroll. so now, how can i scroll automatically?

Comment: please include a working code snippet. With the "import" lines needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)    
element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll")))    
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

I can see your button on a page:

[image]

Comment: it says drivers not defined

Comment: actually i just tried that, but it gives an error like this

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/82103/Desktop/이하늘매크로.py", line 22, in <module>
    element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.chk_pricheckAll")))
  File "C:\Users\82103\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: can you provide your link ? I think your element is under iframe is so then try to switch to iframe before handling your element

Comment: https://www.ehaneul.go.kr:5443/esky_p/esky_index.jsp#MENU:M211000000

Comment: click button that says"화장예약신청"

Comment: sorry not able to identify button on your page.

Comment: check image above i cant see any element with your desscription

Comment: oh i just forgot about that, it's website by goverment, so you need to install keyboard secure program by click orange button says'다운로드'

Comment: I think i figure out what's problam. it need to scroll down until it's visable. but how?

Comment: on the same page in the screensshot : driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: yes because your page dont have any component for scrolling

Comment: so what can i do?